# Set Variable of Launcher View Controller on Task Completion

Tags: swift, macos, asynchronous

I'm doing an `asynchronous` HTTP POST Task, on Completion I need to send back the result to the launcher `viewcontroller`.I have hooked on to the completion handler and everything works as intended. But I cannot properly declare the Return Variable due to this error

`Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`

```
                dourltask() { isValid in 
                // do something with the returned Bool
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.spinner.isHidden=true;
                    self.spinner.stopAnimation(self) if(isValid) {
                  Error ---->     if let presenter presenting as? ViewController {
                            if(isValid) {
                                presenter.bvalue=false
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: `if let presenter = self.presenting as? ViewController {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks.

Comment: @Jack ... I was going to accept your answer... it seems you deleted it.

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804074/nsimage-getting-resized-when-i-draw-text-on-it

Comment: @LeoDabus Im calling the draw text method on the NSImage which is returned by the face detection extension you had provided... Can you please take a look,im stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which
>   is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self
>   property to refer to the current instance within its own instance
>   methods.

```
dourltask() { isValid in 
                // do something with the returned Bool
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.spinner.isHidden=true;
                    self.spinner.stopAnimation(self) if(isValid) {
                    if let presenter = self.presenting as? ViewController {
                            if(isValid) {
                                presenter.bvalue=false
                            }
                        }
                    }
```